# Convert Byte array into collection of items of different types

Tags: c#

I'm recieving UDP messages as byte arrays and depending on details in some of the first byte, I need to convert remaining bytes into a multitude of different possible arrangements of other data types.

These data types are primarily 'uint', 'ushort' and just 'byte' but can be in any order, and there can be any number of them. Each of these items will have a named variable.

I've tried using quite a few different options and am getting close, but feel that the methods I've created are not the best they could be. In places I've wanted to use 'sizeof' but don't want to mark the code as 'unsafe'. I've tried to use the 'params' keyword on the input, but this cannot be in conjunction with 'ref'. I've wanted to pass them with a maximum number of T1, T2, etc. using generics, but realised I can't enumerate these. I'm now passing an array of variables in conjunction with the 'ref' keyword, which means creating the array in memory but only the array gets updated with the changed and not the original variables.

```
byte[] message = new byte[] { }; //some byte array
ushort item1 = default(ushort);
byte item2 = default(byte);
var argumentArray = new object[] { item1, item2 };
ConvertArray(response, ref argumentArray);
```

```
private void ConvertArray(byte[] response, ref object[] items)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = items[i];
        var itemType = item.GetType();
        var itemSize = SizeOf(item.GetType());

        if (itemSize == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (itemSize == 1)
        {
            items[i] = response[index];
        }
        else
        {
            var method = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod($"To{itemType.Name}");
            var returned = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { response, index });
            items[i] = Convert.ChangeType(returned, itemType);
        }

        index = index + itemSize;
     }
}
```

```
private int SizeOf(Type type)
{
   switch (type.Name)
   {
       case nameof(UInt16):
           return 2;

       case "Byte":
           return 1;

       default:
           return 0;
   }
}
```

So this is partially working in that 'argumentArray' is updating with the values from the 'ConvertArray' method, but I'm sure there is a neater way to do this using Types.

Ideally I wouldn't need to create the 'argumentArray' and just pass the items (e.g. Item1 and Item2) directly as arguments to the method.

Comment: So what is actually the question here?

Comment: Yes, there are certainly, *certainly* neater ways to do this than using reflection to get methods on `BitConverter` and using `Convert`, but if you want advice on how to improve working code, and you can make your concerns specific (rather than "make it look better somehow"), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better venue. (If it *doesn't* work right now, it's not clear in what way it doesn't work.)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I could maybe rewrite the final line as: "How can I rewrite the ConvertArray method by just passing the items and not an argumentArray."

Comment: Is `(params object[] args)` what you're looking for? You could then construct a new array inside, and return it after populating it

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen but returning the array I'd still need to assign back to the original variable. Again, ideally I'd be able to use 'out'/'ref' in conjunction with 'params'.